# Xquery Top Function

Tags: xquery

How can I achieve something similar to the TOP function is SQL using Xquery?  In other words, how can I select the top 5 elements of something with ties?  This should be simple but I'm having trouble finding it with Google.

An example of some data I might want to format looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <value> 
        <a>first</a>
        <b>1</b>
    </value>
    <value> 
        <a>third</a>
        <b>3</b>
    </value>
    <value> 
        <a>second</a>
        <b>2</b>
    </value>
    <value> 
        <a>2nd</a>
        <b>2</b>
    </value>
</root>
```

I want to sort by b for all of the values and return a.  To illustrate my problem, say I want to return the top two values with ties.

Thanks

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, correct and short solution. Do note that @kadalamittai's answer is incorrect (syntactically invalid) and @lavinio's answer is a little bit too-long. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For the provided source XML document**:

```
<root>
  <value> 
    <a>first</a>
    <b>1</b>
  </value>
  <value> 
    <a>third</a>
    <b>3</b>
  </value>
  <value> 
    <a>second</a>
    <b>2</b>
  </value>
  <value> 
    <a>2nd</a>
    <b>2</b>
  </value>
</root>
```

**To get the first two results "with ties" use**:

```
let $vals := 
  for $k in distinct-values(/*/*/b/xs:integer(.)) 
    order by $k
    return $k
 return
  for $a in /*/value[index-of($vals,xs:integer(b)) le 2]/a
      order by $a/../b/xs:integer(.)
    return $a
```

**When this expression is evaluated, the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<a>first</a>
<a>second</a>
<a>2nd</a>
```

**Explanation**:

1. **We specify in `$vals` the sorted sequence of all distinct values of `/*/*/b`, used as integers**. This is necessary, because the function **[`distinct-values()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-distinct-values)** is not guaranteed to produce its result sequence in any predefined order. Also, if we do not convert the values to `xs:integer` before sorting, they would be sorted as strings and this would generally produce incorrect results.
2. **Then we select only those `/*/value/a` whose b-sibling's index in the sorted sequence of distinct integer `b-values` is less or equal to 2**.
3. **Finally, we need to sort the results** by their  b-sibling's integer values, because otherwise they will be selected in document order

**Do note**:

**Only this solution at present produces correctly sorted results** for any integer values of `/*/*/b`.

Comment: Sorry, but Alejandro's right, I didn't provide enough information for what I'm looking for.  I've updated my question with newer information.  Thanks for the reply though.

Comment: @helixed: Thanks for letting me know. I have edited my answer and now it provides a solution for the updated problem. :)

Comment: Wow, this is probably the most detailed and well explained answer I've gotten on this site.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

To filter a sequence to the first 5 items you use the `fn:position()` function:

```
$sequence[position() le 5]
```

Do note that when the sequence to filter is a node set resultion from an `/` step operation, the predicate works againts the last axis. So, maybe you would need to wrap that expression between parentesis.

But, to filter a "calculated sequence" (like sorting or tuples filter conditions), you need to use the full power of the `FLWOR` expression.

This XQuery:

```
(for $value in /root/value
 order by $value/b
 return $value/a)[position() le 2]
```

Output:

```
<a>first</a><a>second</a>
```

**Note**: This is a simple sort. The filter is the outer most expression because this allows lazy avaluation.

This XQuery:

```
for $key in (for $val in distinct-values(/root/value/b)
             order by xs:integer($val)
             return $val)[position() le 2]
return /root/value[b=$key]/a
```

Output:

```
<a>first</a><a>second</a><a>2nd</a>
```

**Note**: This order the keys first an then return all the result for the first two keys.

**Edit**: Added explicit integer casting.

Comment: You're right.  I updated my question with more of a description of what I'm looking for.  For this problem I do need to utilize a FLWOR expression.

Comment: @Alejandro: There are at least two significant problems with this. Please, check the results with b-values that are random integers.

Comment: @Dimitre: Thanks, I've missed the number casting.

Comment: @Alejandro: this is one of the two problems.

Comment: @Dimitre: The document order problem is not present with my expression because keys are taken from the sorted sequence in order. Sequences have the explicit order of construction.

Comment: @Alejandro: Yes, I see now -- I was misled by the improper (lack of) indentation of the `return` clause... I usually indent the `return` to the right od `for` so that it is immediately obvious to whish `for` the `return` belongs. Another misleading fact in your expression is the use of general equality. Not only is this less efficient, but, more importantly, it made me believe that you are comparing the single `b-value` to all `$key` values.

Comment: @Alejandro: Good that you added integer sorting. Another, minor thing is to replace the general comparison with value comparison.

Answer (score 1):

You can use XPath on the Node with top limit as indexes

```
    <one>
  <two>a</two>
  <two>b</two>
  <two>c</two>
  <two>d</two>
  <two>e</two>
  <two>f</two>
  <two>g</two>
  <two>h</two>
   </one>
```

Then

```
$xml_data/one/two[ 1 to 5 ]

$xml_data/one/two[ some_number to fn:last() ]
```

Comment: Does this handle ties though?

Comment: This answer is incorrect, here is the error message from Saxon: ""FORG0006: `Effective boolean value is not defined for a sequence of two or more items starting with a numeric value`"

Comment: we are doing a sequence operation and not a boolean operation. its a standard XPATH op.

Answer (score 0):

With sample input

```
<one>
  <two>a</two>
  <two>b</two>
  <two>c</two>
  <two>d</two>
  <two>e</two>
  <two>f</two>
  <two>g</two>
  <two>h</two>
</one>
```

The following is one way to get the first five rows:

```
for $two at $index in /one/two
  where $index <= 5
  return $two
```

Comment: Is there a way to adapt this for ties?

Comment: I just want to say that I haven't downvoted your answer. Whoever did this probably didn't know that the OP only recently updated his question. :(

Answer (score -1):

In the MySQL dialect it's not called TOP, but LIMIT. When you google for "limit xquery" you will find:

http://osdir.com/ml/text.xml.exist/2004-02/msg00214.html

and

http://osdir.com/ml/text.xml.exist/2004-08/msg00115.html